# Kernel of projection formula

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

For a closed embedding of compact complex manifolds
$$
\iota : Y \hookrightarrow X
$$
and any $\alpha \in H^*(X,\mathbb Q)$, we have trivially:
$$
\iota^*(\alpha)=0\quad \Rightarrow \quad\iota_*\iota^*(\alpha)=0.
$$
My question is: does the converse hold? So does $\iota_*\iota^*(\alpha)=0$ imply that $\iota^*(\alpha)=0$?
If not: can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true.

Consider a Hopf surface $X=(\mathbb C^2\backslash \{0\})/((z_1,z_2)\sim (2z_1,2z_2))\simeq S^3\times S^1$. It contains a "coordinate" elliptic curve $Y=(\mathbb C\backslash \{0\})/(z_1\sim 2z_1)\simeq S^1\times S^1$.

Let us use Poincare-dual language to operate $i^*$ and $i_*$. Take $\alpha\in H^1(X)$ to be the class dual to the cycle $S^3\times pt$, then the class
$$
i^*(\alpha)\in H^1(Y)
$$
is dual to the cycle $S^1\times pt\subset S^1\times S^1$ and nonzero. Direct image of this cycle in $H_1(X)$ is zero, hence
$$
i_*i^*(\alpha)\in H^3(X)
$$
also vanishes.